# Working with structs in Solidity and web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, struct

I'm trying to interact with this contract via [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/).

Something *like* [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/returning-a-struct-and-reading-via-web3) seems to be the right path to take, but I can't figure out how to implement that logic in my contract.

When `getAdopters()` is called, I see the following error in my browser's console:

`invalid solidity type!: tuple[16]`

Here's the code where `getAdopters()` is called:

```
  markAdopted: function(owners, account) {
    var adoptionInstance;

    App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      adoptionInstance = instance;

      return adoptionInstance.getAdopters.call();

    }).then(function(owners) {
      for (i = 0; i < owners.length; i++) {
        if (owners[i] !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
            $('.panel-pet').eq(i).find('button').text('Success').attr('disabled', true);
            var loc = document.getElementById('owned-by');
            loc.innerHTML += owners[i];
            console.log(valueOf(owners[0]));

        }
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },
```

**Ultimately, how can I return the fields of the struct as separate return variables, and then access them using [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty similar to this one:

[How to return an array of structs (or an array of destructured structs) in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39520/how-to-return-an-array-of-structs-or-an-array-of-destructured-structs-in-solid/39527)

Look over the comments, particularly with regards to "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;"

Updated..

Based on your comments, I think this is what you're looking for.  The values from the structs will be returned to web3 as arrays of the struct values.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract Adoption {
    struct Pet {
        address owner;
        uint256 price;
    }

    Pet[16] data;

    function Adoption() public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            data[i].owner = msg.sender;
            data[i].price = i;
        }
    }

    function getAdopters() external view returns (address[],uint256[]) {
        address[] memory owners = new address[](16);
        uint256[] memory prices =  new uint256[](16);
        for (uint i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            owners[i] = (data[i].owner);
            prices[i] = (data[i].price);
        }
        return (owners,prices);
    }
}
```

Some JS test code in test.js script:

```
module.exports = () => {
    const Adoption = artifacts.require('Adoption');
    return Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        adoptionInstance = instance;

        return adoptionInstance.getAdopters.call()
            .then(adopters => {
                const [ owners, prices ] = adopters;
                for (let i = 0; i < owners.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`owner=${owners[i]}, price=${prices[i].valueOf()}`);
                }
            });
    });
};
```

I tested using truffle

```
$ truffle exec --network ganache test.js 
Using network 'ganache'.

owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=0
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=1
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=2
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=3
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=4
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=5
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=6
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=7
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=8
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=9
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=10
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=11
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=12
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=13
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=14
owner=0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, price=15
```

Comment: They say "just be aware that any web clients running web3.js will have issues". I'm using web3.js.

Comment: There are other libraries that supposedly support it.  Checkout out Ethers.. https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/ .   Is web3.js a must?  If it is, or you want to write a contract that would work with as many clients as possible, then returning structs from a public/external method is something you'll have to do without.

Comment: My question is "how can I return the fields of the struct as separate return variables, and then access them using web3.js?".

Comment: function getData(uint8 _index) external view returns (uint8,string) {
        return (data[_index].id, data[_index].name);
    }
webjs would receive this as an array.

Comment: how can I change my `getAdopters()` function such that web3js receives it as an array? if you can just help me with that, I'd be glad to accept your answer

Comment: See my update..

Comment: ah, this looks great
! what would I need to do with the corresponding `markAdopted()` function in my js file?

Comment: I don't have a dev environment handy to test it, but you'd call the contract getAdopters function and should receive an array back where element 0 is the owners array, and element 1 is the prices array.  The prices will likely come back as BN objects, you can call valueOf() on those to get the values.

Comment: thanks for that. It seems like `owners` is being returned as an empty array. In the console, I see `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. I've edited my question with my updated js code. What do you think I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I added some js sample code to my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: without using ES6 conventions, what would that look like within my current `markAdopted()` function?

Comment: Sorry, but I think we've hit the end of the road on this one.  Best of luck to you.